# Where to put meta info (__version__ etc) in a Python project?

Tags: python, metadata, setup.py

I have a little Python2/3 project with the directory structure

```
superproject/
    ->  __init__.py
    ->  meta.py
setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` file contains a bunch of `import`s and actual code, meta has

```
 __author__ = 'John Doe'
 __author_email__ = 'john@doe.com'
 __version__ = '1.2.3'
 # [...]
```

I would like to make the meta info available in setup.py (simple: just `import superproject.meta`) and in `superproject` as

```
import superproject
print(superproject.__version__)
```

I'm struggling with the latter requirement. When doing

```
from .meta import *
```

in `__init__.py`, I can only do

```
print(superproject.meta.__version__)
```

for example.

Note that, I cannot put the meta info in `__init__.py` directly since I'd have to `import superproject` in `setup.py`, and the numerous `import` dependencies of `superproject` aren't available then yet.

Any hints?

Comment: More options for this apparently intractable problem: https://packaging.python.org/single_source_version/

Comment: @jwodder Just what I was looking for. If you promote this to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it a solution.

Comment: see also [bumpversion](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bumpversion)

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: It's a link-only "answer."  If I promoted it to an answer, I would downvote and flag it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known problem and the Python Software Foundation has an entire article about it: [Single-sourcing the Project Version](https://packaging.python.org/single_source_version/).

I played around with all the suggestions and eventually decided on the following solution.

1. Rename `meta.py` to `__about__.py` and `from ... import ...` it in `__init__.py`.
2. In `setup.py`, `exec` `__about__.py` into a dictionary and use that information.

This provides all meta information as `superproject.__about__.__version__` as well as `superproject.__version__`. Also, this makes it easy to `import` meta info from other submodules of `superproject`.

While it adds a little complexity to `setup.py`, it leaves the actual project code largely untouched. I don't really care how complex `setup.py` gets, as long as it's remotely maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import importlib

meta = importlib.import_module ("mod.meta")
print (meta.__author__)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more verbose? I don't understand how this is helping yet.

Comment: I thought you're interested in setup.py, so this snippet belongs there. Do you need to access metadata from the rest of your project?

Comment: That'd be nice, but not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this from a file in project root. Include this file in `data_files` in `setup.py` [docs](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#data-files). JSON is probably the easiest format to use.

as in

```
superproject/
    ->  __init__.py
setup.py
meta.json
```

Comment: How to make the info available in the installation as `superproject.__version__` then?

Comment: read the json file and set the variable, do the same in the setup.py file